# Should I create a smart contract for my marketplace?

Tags: contract-development

I'm new to blockchain and smart contract technology, and I want to build a marketplace to basically sell NFT tickets to shows, but this tickets will be minted by users that wants to re-sell your previous ticket but can't go more for the show.

I saw many videos and tutorials creating a smart contract to store and sell the NFTs, but when I went to OpenSea, grabbing some examples of usability, I saw that in OpenSea, you can sell NFTs from your own contract. My question is if in my case, the more correct is create a smart contract to the marketplace, and the users that want to sell your tickets will mint the NFT in this contract OR if similar to the OpenSea, users will create a contract to the show ticket (similar to Collection creation).

Is there any especification about use cases of this two approachs? Witch will be better to my marketplace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, creating a separate smart contract for your marketplace is a better approach than having users create their own contracts, like OpenSea. OpenSea can be too complicated for what you want to do.

A simpler method is to make one contract for the marketplace where users can mint and sell their NFT tickets. This will help manage the tickets more efficiently. Remember to create a specific NFT with an expiry date to protect your users. After the expiry date, the NFT should be burnt or not transferrable.